# By what is the alternating group generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do I prove that the alternating group $A_n$ is generated by the set $\{(1\space 2\space i):i=3,4,...,n\}$?

Can I do this with induction, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: let $i,j$ and $k$ be different natural numbers $\geq 3$. Then $$(1 2 j)^{-1}(1 2 i)(1 2 j)=(2 j i)$$ and$$(1 2 k)^{-1}(2 j i)(1 2 k)= (k j i ).$$ And it is well-know that $A_n$ is generated by $3$-cycles. (You have to check $n=3, 4$ separately. But I gave a hint and you do the rest!)

Comment: what does this mean?

Comment: could you help me some more? I can't figure this out